# What is the technical name for ".\" when logging into a local account for windows?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, windows-domain, local

I know that you can you can use .\ in place for for the computer name when logging into a local account on Windows (Ex: ComputerName\Username = .\Username).

What is the technical term or nomenclature for using .\ besides "dot backslash"?

Comment: Not sure! Here are some other takes on it, ultimately not being conclusive on a proper name: https://serverfault.com/questions/430638/is-there-a-specific-name-for-the-dot-slash-shorthand-used-to-log-onto-a-w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really have a name. Most often it's called "Dot Slash Login"
or "local login".

Some example links :

- [The Dot Slash Login Shortcut](https://polarclouds.co.uk/dot-slash-login-shortcut/)
- [Is there a specific name for the "." (dot-slash) shorthand used to log onto a Windows machine?](https://serverfault.com/questions/430638/is-there-a-specific-name-for-the-dot-slash-shorthand-used-to-log-onto-a-w?_gl=1*b4bo8y*_ga*OTU2OTY1MzE2LjE1MTg0NDc4OTE.*_ga_S812YQPLT2*MTY3NDc0NTkwMy41MDkuMS4xNjc0NzQ2NTE5LjAuMC4w)